# Bars not displaying in jqplot bar chart

Tags: jqplot, bar-chart

My problem is that bars are not displaying at all in a bar chart, using JqPlot.

Here is the code:

```
var line = [['Clients' , 15] , ['Prospects' , 8]];
var plot4 = jQuery.jqplot('chartdiv4', [line] ,
                            {
                                seriesDefaults:{
                                    renderer:jQuery.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                                    rendererOptions: {
                                        varyBarColor: true
                                        }
                                },
                                axes:{
                                    xaxis:{
                                        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                                    }
                                }
                              });
```

Comment: Is your plot drawn empty? Or not at all?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is drawn empty, olny with no bars

Comment: Can you elaborate on what chart are you trying to achieve? Normally you would put 'Clients' and 'Prospects' as ticks (to show on the xaxis)... so... I'm not sure on your final purpose.

Comment: Yes exactly, I need 2 bars (clients and prospects), with labels below. Can you give me a hint about the properties I should use for what you call 'ticks'? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the example at http://jsfiddle.net/BpEK2/3/
This shows bars being drawn on the screen. Make sure you look at the included dependencies (external resources) as you'll need all of them. In essence, what you need to do is

```
var s1 = [15, 8];

var ticks = ['Clients', 'Prospects'];

var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            fillToZero: true, 
            varyBarColor: true
        }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: ticks
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: you need the following:
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/jquery.jqplot.js
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/jquery.jqplot.css

As well as jQuery, off course. Did you make sure you included ALL those?

Comment: I used another JS file instead of "categoryAxisRenderer". Apparently that was the problem. Thank you so much @mihaimm. Problem solved!